# How to accomplish this query with RavenDb?

Tags: ravendb

I'm wondering what's the best approach for getting back the total number of records for a search, and at the same time, get back the Nth 128 record block segment of data which seems to be the cap imposed by RavenDb run-time.

For instance given this query, I also need to know the total number of records.

```
var bookmarks = session.Query<Bookmark>()
  .OrderByDescending(i => i.DateCreated)
  .Skip(pageCount * (pageNumber – 1))
  .Take(pageCount)
  .ToList();
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
RavenQueryStatistics stats;
var bookmarks = session.Query<Bookmark>()
  .OrderByDescending(i => i.DateCreated)
  .Skip(pageCount * (pageNumber – 1))
  .Take(pageCount)
  .Statistics(out stats)
  .ToList();

int bookmarksFound = stats.TotalResults;
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel! I had a hunch that they knew this had to be implemented if they were going to throttle the results. Very well played.